# RuntimeError: Failed to load SavedModel or .h5 model. Cannot find the Placeholder op that is an input to the ReadVariableOp

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying convert and save my model to CoreML. I am using tf.keras and here is my code.

```
import keras
import coremltools
import tensorflow as tf

keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('machine.h5')

print(keras_model.input.name)
print(keras_model.input_shape)
print(keras_model.output.name)

output_labels = ['0', '1']

keras_model= coremltools.converters.tensorflow.convert(
'machine.h5', input_name_shape_dict={'embedding_input': (None, 24)},
output_feature_names=['Identity'])

model.save('xcodeModel.mlmodel')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shenoyaar/MACHINES_LEARN/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py", line 213, in _graph_def_from_saved_model_or_keras_model
    frozen_func = _convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(concrete_func)
  File "/Users/shenoyaar/MACHINES_LEARN/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 506, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2
    raise ValueError("Cannot find the Placeholder op that is an input "
ValueError: Cannot find the Placeholder op that is an input to the ReadVariableOp.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 15, in <module>
    output_feature_names=['Identity'])
  File "/Users/shenoyaar/MACHINES_LEARN/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py", line 160, in convert
    filename = _graph_def_from_saved_model_or_keras_model(filename)
  File "/Users/shenoyaar/MACHINES_LEARN/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py", line 218, in _graph_def_from_saved_model_or_keras_model
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to load SavedModel or .h5 model. {}.'.format(e))
RuntimeError: Failed to load SavedModel or .h5 model. Cannot find the Placeholder op that is an input to the ReadVariableOp..
```

This is a text classification model not an image one.

Comment: Before answering, you should read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest